# Extracting data from matplotlib figure containing PolyCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a `matplotlib` figure containing a PolyCollection, the figure resembles the following:

[image: Figureforextraction]

What I would like is to extract the color data, i.e. the array of colors (here black or white) and the corresponding `x` and `y` values.

For reference the code used to generate the picture is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

verts = []

def polygon_under_graph(xlist, ylist):
    """
    Construct the vertex list which defines the polygon filling the space under
    the (xlist, ylist) line graph.  Assumes the xs are in ascending order.
    """
    return [(xlist[0], 0.), *zip(xlist, ylist), (xlist[-1], 0.)]


# Set up the x sequence
xs = np.linspace(0., 10., 26)

ys = np.random.rand(len(xs))
verts.append(polygon_under_graph(xs, ys))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(frameon=False)

poly = PolyCollection(verts,facecolors='k',edgecolors= 'k')
ax.add_collection(poly)
```

I have tried using  `poly.get_array()` but nothing was returned.

Any suggestions on how to proceed ?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "extract the color data, i.e. the array of colors (here black or white) and the corresponding x and y values.". What are the "corresponding x and y values"? Provide some example? How do you assign a vertex to black or white color?

Comment: For the polygon you created, try this: `poly.get_facecolor(), poly.get_edgecolor(), poly.get_paths()`. For the vertices of it, try `poly.get_paths()[0].vertices`.